# Pegjs reserved keyword

Tags: javascript, pegjs

I got a grammar supporting this:
AND, OR, NOT, ( and ), ", '

Few samples of things I need to be able parse:

- a1 OR a2
- a1 a2 (same as above)
- a1 AND a2
- "a1" AND 'a2'
- a1 OR a2 NOT a3
- a1 a2 OR "a3" NOT(a1 AND a2 'a6')

Considering a1, a2, and so on are real user input that could include almost anything like:

- 123
- Tesla-S
- origami

The problem I got, is when one of those word are without quotes, and starts with some reserved keyword, for example:

- origami
- andromede

In this case, this parser consider:

- or keyword + igami text
- and keyword + romede text

That's the problem I got.

I've tried for two days various solutions, found on stackoverflow (and official doc):

- [Pegjs: Don't allow reserved keywords as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976820/pegjs-dont-allow-reserved-keywords-as-a-variable-name)

(and many other) trying to find a solution with those constraint:

- it's not guarantee that there is space before/after keyword, for example "a1 AND(a2 OR a3)" is valid (no space between "AND" and "("), so is "(a1 AND a2)OR a3" => a keyword could have before/after it, a space and/or "("/")" (but when I try this I break the parenthesis rule)
- a word is NOT a word only if it's part of the reserved section: "AND"i / "OR"i / "NOT"i / "(" / ")" / "'" / '"' / " " => any of those are not a word, anything else is, like ando is a word, not a keyword.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
content = andOperator

andOperator
    = head:orOperator tail:(_ "AND"i _ orOperator)* {
        return tail.reduce(function(result, element) {
            return {
                type: "and",
                value: {
                    left: result,
                    right: element[3]
                }
            };
        }, head);
    }

orOperator
    = head:notOperator tail:(_ ("OR"i / _) _ notOperator)* {
        return tail.reduce(function(result, element) {
            return {
                type: "or",
                value: {
                    left: result,
                    right: element[3]
                }
            };
        }, head);
    }

notOperator
    = head:parenthesis tail:(_ ("AND"i / "OR" / _) _ "NOT"i _ parenthesis)* {
        return tail.reduce(function(result, element) {
            var type = (element[1] && element[1].toLowerCase() === "or") ? "or" : "and";
            return {
                type: type,
                value: {
                    left: result,
                    right: {
                        type: "not",
                        value: element[5]
                    }
                }
            };
        }, head);
    }

parenthesis "Parenthesis"
    = _ "(" _ inside:content+ _ ")" _ {
        return {
            type: "parenthesis",
            value: (Array.isArray(inside) && inside.length === 1) ? inside[0] : inside
        };
    } / text

/*
-----------------------------
  TEXT
-----------------------------
*/

text "Text"
    = _ inside:(singleQuoteText / doubleQuoteText / noQuoteText)+ _ {
        return (Array.isArray(inside) && inside.length === 1) ? inside[0] : inside;
    }

singleQuoteText "Single Quote Text"
    = "'" text:$([^\']+) "'" {
        return {
            type: "text",
            value: text ? text.trim(): text
        };
    }

doubleQuoteText "Double Quote Text"
    = '"' text:$([^\"]+) '"' {
        return {
            type: "text",
            value: text ? text.trim(): text
        };
    }

noQuoteText "No Quote Text"
    = text:$(!reserved .)+ {
        return {
            type: "text",
            value: text ? text.trim(): text
        };
    }

reserved "List of keyword this grammar allow"
    = ("AND"i / "OR"i / "NOT"i / "(" / ")" / "'" / '"' / " ")

/*
-----------------------------
  WHITESPACE PARSING
-----------------------------
*/
__ "Mandatory Whitespace"
    = $(whitespace+)

_ "Optional Whitespace"
    = __?

whitespace
    = [\u0009\u000B\u000C\u0020\u00A0\uFEFF\u1680\u180E\u2000-\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000] / $('\r\n' / '\n')
```

Example of the problem: hello origami

Gives with the current grammar:

```
{
   "type": "or",
   "value": {
      "left": {
         "type": "text",
         "value": "hello"
      },
      "right": {
         "type": "text",
         "value": "igami"
      }
   }
}
```

Should gives (it has consider origami as a full world and not or + igami):

```
{
   "type": "or",
   "value": {
      "left": {
         "type": "text",
         "value": "hello"
      },
      "right": {
         "type": "text",
         "value": "origami"
      }
   }
}
```

Origami in the current parser is splitted as OR + igami, while it should have consider the whole word origami...

Comment: No one has an idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a predicate, you can include a rule that matches all words except your keywords, like so:

```
{

   var keywords = ["and", "or"];

}

Expression =
    word:$(Word) { return { word: word } } /
    keyword:$(Keyword) { return { keyword: keyword } }

// Word will match everything except "and" and "or",
// including words like "origami" and "andromede"
Word = word:$([a-zA-Z]+) &{ return !keywords.includes(word) }

Keyword = [a-zA-Z]+
```

In the above grammar, `Word` will match all words except "or" and "and". If the word (then *entire* word) is one of those keywords, then the `Keyword` rule will match instead.

So, given the input `and`, you will get the following output:

```
{
    keyword: "and"
}
```

But given the input `andromede`, you will get the following output:

```
{
    word: "andromede"
}
```